# Is it possible in Spark to run independent stages sequentially?

Tags: java, apache-spark, parallel-processing, sequential, stage

I'm running a job in Spark having two independent stages that run in parallel sharing the resources.

The problems I'm facing are two (assuming max 64 concurrent tasks):

1. The running tasks are unbalanced between the stages.
   [image]
2. When a stage ends, the other stage doesn't increase the number of executing tasks.
   [image]

In particular, I would like to avoid the second case (maybe the first one is caused by the FIFO policy for tasks), because sometimes a lot of work is done without exploiting all the resources. Note that this issue doesn't happen always.

Is it possible to avoid this situation sequentializing also the independent stages? I have found this possibility for the jobs, not for the stages.